# Accessing services internally in k8s cluster in addition to exposing them outside through ingress

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have configured two services, both as `NodePort`.

## Service 1

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: bitcoinrpc-dev-service
  namespace: dev
spec:
  selector:
    app: bitcoin-node
  ports:
  - name: bitcoin-mainnet
    protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 8332
  - name: bitcoin-testnet
    protocol: TCP
    port: 8080
    targetPort: 18332  
  type: NodePort
```

## Service 2

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: counterpartyrpc-dev-service
  namespace: dev
spec:
  selector:
    app: counterparty-node
  ports:
  - name: mainnet
    protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 4000
  - name: testnet
    protocol: TCP
    port: 8080
    targetPort: 14000  
  type: NodePort
```

I can access both these services outside the cluster through an ingress. However, when I try to connect to `service1(bitcoin` from `service2(counterparty)`, it keeps losing connection. I am referring the service as `bitcoinrpc-dev-service.dev.svc.cluster.local:80`

However, if I refer this service as hostname configured in `ingress`, the connection is much more stable. e.g. when I refer `service1` by `bitcoin.mydomain.com:80`

Since, this would mean routing the traffice outside the cluster when both the services that need to communicate to each other are in the same cluster, it seems slightly inefficient.

I tried changing the `servicetype` to `clusterIP`, however then I can't access them through ingress.

What should be the correct configuration?

Comment: Just to clarify, your services are not communicating with each other. In GKE, the service really just translates to a set of iptable rules that get applied to each node and such they can't talk to each other.

Comment: Also, you mention that it is "losing the connection." Is there an error message? Your statement implies the connection is being made but not kept and as such the issue will not be with kube-dns or routing

Answer (score 1):

The reason behind that is only k8s cluster with kube-dns add ons can translate the domain name `bitcoinrpc-dev-service.dev.svc.cluster.local:80` to its corresponding IP address.

Have a look at this great answer which shows the solutions around this issue:

> [How to access a service in a kubernetes cluster using the service name .](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47027194/how-to-access-a-service-in-a-kubernetes-cluster-using-the-service-name)

Comment: I think `kube-dns` is enabled by default, also it intermittently can connect just that the connection is unstable. Does the answer imply that it's ok to connect through the hostname specified in the `ingress`?

Comment: Yes, ingress is used specially for routing your traffic to internal services and hence you can use the hostname specified in the ingress to connect to the service

Comment: I mean, is it ok to connect from one service to another, both within the same cluster and use ingress to route the traffic for the same?

Comment: I believe It is OK to connect to another service within the cluster using ingress path,but my main concern is here that why you're not having the stable path with `svc.cluster.local` while I am having the stable connection.

Comment: That is exactly my original question :D

Comment: Since you are routing traffic internally within the cluster, you should be using the cluster IP of the service. Your name resolution through kube-dns should be using the cluster IP already (try an nslookup of the service name from a pod). Also, yes, kube-dns on GKE is pre-installed